# Socket.io, clean/disable buffer or cache

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm using Socket.io client and I noticed that if the connection is lost(I closed the server) Socket.io will try to reconnect, while it reconnect I can still call `emit()`, the problem is that when I reactivate the server, Socket.io saved all my `emit()` calls and it will send all of them, at once, on successful reconnection, is there a way to clean that buffer upon `reconnect_attempt` event or not having this buffer at all, or is it kind of cache option I can disabled?